# Is there a pixel constraint when printing in Portrait mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to print an html page in portrait mode and the right side gets cut off when the width of the content is close to 800px wide. Is there a pixel constraint when printing in portrait mode?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pixels to inches calculator. 800px is close to 11inches.  So you are getting close to the width of standard paper.

http://tiporama.com/tools/pixels_inches.html

Comment: Right, so I add some padding around my print area which leaves me with about 7.5 inches wide - approximately 562 pixels. If my content is wider than that then I'm basically screwed.

Comment: @fumeng I believe so.  I can't see your code, or know exactly what you're trying to achieve.  Here's a good lesson on setting up a print css file: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: I'll try and clean up my code. But basically I've got a row with 6 td cells going across that are filled with dynamic data. For some reason it can go up to 699px wide and print in portrait mode. But the edge case, where someone's name or address is more than 50/60 characters long then it starts getting cut off on the right hand side when printing.

Comment: @fumeng  You could look into css word wrap and word break.  Might help you out.

Comment: Thank you. I've defintely used both of those and they're certainly part of the solution, but not the whole. The top row used to be 5 td cells instead of 6 and this sixth cell I've added is at least 175px long. So, I think the @media print{} css mentioned in the link you posted is where the rest of my changes lie, i.e. shrinking font-sizes, truncating text, etc..